# How to sort a matrix by one row - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So having a matrix like this:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
[1. 0. 3. 4. 4.]]
```

How do I sort it by the last row, so that the contents of the columns stay the same like this:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
[0. 1. 3. 4. 4.]]
```

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
num_seq = 10
seq_len = 5
seq_width = 5

con = np.random.randint(0, seq_width,size=seq_len)

seq = np.zeros((seq_len, seq_width))

seq[np.arange(seq_len), con] = 1
seq[seq_len-1, np.arange(seq_width)] = con

out = np.sort(seq, axis=1)
```

And getting an output that looks like this:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 3. 4. 4.]]
```

Comment: I would take a copy of the last row and make a pair of the values with their indices as tuples. Then sort by the values and extract the indices and sort the remaining columns using that as a base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`np.argsort()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and some numpy slicing. Using your example array:

```
arr = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 3, 4, 4]])
arr[:, np.argsort(arr[-1, :])]
# array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 3, 4, 4]])
```

Basically the `np.argsort(arr[-1, :])` returns the *indices* of the last row of `arr` in order of the ascending value of the *content* of that last row. This returns `array([1, 0, 2, 3, 4])` for the example you gave.

Then we just grab all rows with the columns in that order with `arr[:, np.argsort(arr[-1, :])]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`arr[:, arr[-1, :].argsort()]`

Answer (score 0):

This does what you require, although the numpy approach is cleaner and better, in my opinion. It depends on whether your matrix is truly a matrix, or an array or a list of lists. If you can't use numpy for whatever reason, then this solution should work independently, even if it's a bit hacky.

```
your_matrix = [[0, 1., 0., 0., 0.],
                   [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                   [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,],
                   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
                   [1., 0., 3., 4., 4.]]

your_last_row = your_matrix[-1]
#add indices
reference_row = [(idx, value) for (idx, value) in enumerate(your_last_row)]
ref_row_sorted = sorted(reference_row, key=lambda x: x[1])

#extract indices
indices = [x[0] for x in ref_row_sorted]

new_matrix = []
for row in your_matrix:
    new_row = [row[x] for x in indices]
    new_matrix.append(new_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using argsort to select con as the index:

```
import numpy as np

num_seq = 10
seq_len = 5
seq_width = 5

con = np.random.randint(0, seq_width,size=seq_len)

seq = np.zeros((seq_len, seq_width))

seq[np.arange(seq_len), con] = 1
seq[seq_len-1, np.arange(seq_width)] = con


i = np.argsort(con)
seq = seq[:,i]

print(con)
print(seq)
```